stacking calculated field to dataset with other metircs
I have a dataset where rows correspond to different metrics collected at different points in time like so:



metric
month
value




opens
jan-24
50


opens
feb-24
23


opens
mar-24
67


clicks
jan-24
19


clicks
feb-24
12


clicks
mar-24
21



I want to work out the CTOR (clicks/ opens) for each month and join (union) it back to the main dataset like so:



metric
month
value




opens
jan-24
50


opens
feb-24
23


opens
mar-24
67


clicks
jan-24
19


clicks
feb-24
12


clicks
mar-24
21


ctor
jan-24
0.38


ctor
feb-24
0.52


ctor
mar-24
0.31



how can I do this without creating many CTEs based on metric? as I need to do this for many calculated metrics.

Will each month always have one opens and one clicks?

The first thing I Noticed is that value field is integer and your CTOR metric has decimal format. I'm not sure if your union will work without transformations in the upper table. So before you make a union, you may want to cast your integer values to according format.
I would try union two tables without casting to decimal format. If an error occurs I will cast integers to decimals.
Try first this: select metric, month, value from table1 union all select metric, month, value from table2.
If an error occurs:
select metric, month, cast(value as decimal) from table1
union all
select metric, month, value from table2


The question says CTOR is calculated as clicks/ opens.

select metric, month, cast(value as decimal) as value from table1 union all select 'CTOR', c.month, c.value*1.0/o.value from (select * from table where metric = 'clicks') c join (select * from table where metric = 'opens') o on c.month = o.month

UNION ALL a select where you calculate the CTOR (clicks/ opens) for each month using a GROUP BY. Do cast etc to get desired decimal format:
select metric, month, value from tbl
UNION ALL
select 'ctor', month,
       cast(1.0 * SUM(case when metric = 'clicks' then value end) /
                  SUM(case when metric = 'opens' then value end) as decimal(10, 2))
from tbl
group by month

If you also need the same order, add
ORDER BY case metric
           when 'opens' then 1
           when 'clicks' then 2
           when 'ctor' then 3
         end,
         month

